# setof/3 and NAF

Tags: prolog, prolog-setof

so I have a set of facts:

```
course(cs61,  "intro to cs")
...
course(cs62b, "data structure")
...
grade(adam,       cs61, spring11, "A")
...
grade(chrisitian, cs61, fall2010, "A-")
```

I need to define a predicate `good_standing(Student)` to determine whether the `Student` got `A` in every class he took. I must use 2 different approaches:

1. use `setof/3`
2. use NAF

on the 1st. I have tried to figure out get `Result_list`: the set of students that got A from every class he took. and then call `member(Student, Result_list)`. But I don't know what to get the `Result_list` since the syntax is a bit strange to me.

Comment: so, the canonical comment, [what have you tried](http://mattgemmell.com/2008/12/08/what-have-you-tried/) so far?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1) For the NAF solution you should keep in mind that the good-standing student is the one with no grades lower than A, i.e., the one such that there is no course he/she took and the grade is lower than A. We also require this person to take at least one course.

```
good_standing(Student) :- grade(Student, _,_,_), 
                          \+ (grade(Student, Course, _, Grade), 
                              lower(Grade,"A")).
```

with lower/2 defining relation between the grades:

```
lower("A-","A").
lower("B","A").
...
```

The solution above works if students get only one grade per course.

2) For the setof solution you can find all grades per student and check that they are A.

```
grade(Student, Grade) :- grade(Student, _,_,Grade).
good_standing(Student) :- setof(Grade, grade(Student,Grade), ["A"]).
```

Alternatively, as suggested by **false** we can make the existential quantification explicit within setof:

```
good_standing(Student) :- setof(Grade, 
                                Course^Period^grade(Student,Course,Period,Grade),
                                ["A"]).
```

Comment: `good_standing(Student) :-
       setof(Grade, Course^Year^grade(Student,Course,Year,Grade), ["A"]).`

Comment: Thank you! I'm going to edit my answer to include your suggestion.

Comment: Concerning lower "A", it might have been meant to mean not "A".  Thus using a "for all" with negation `\+ ( G, \+ P )`

Comment: I thought they also might have A+ but indeed, the suggestion to use setof might indicate that A is the highest grade.